# Как получить этот файл на устройстве

Tags: c++, qt, ios, iphone

Я разрабатываю приложение на iOS с использованием С++/Qt QML. В логике приложения у меня зашита ситуация когда приложение аварийно падает, то стек падения я записываю в файл лежащий в локальных данных приложения устройства(Iphone). Можно ли как то получить этот файл? Почему мне это нужно? Мне нужно это для того чтобы человек, который тестировал мое приложение мог отсылать мне этот файл со стеком падения.

Comment: А посмотрите в строну сервисов централизованного сбора логов - что то вроде Logstash, sentry.io?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/acquiring-crash-reports-and-diagnostic-logs

Comment: Спасибо. А возможно ли как то записать этот файл в доступное место на телефоне?